# "наконец" vs "наконец-то"

Tags: словоупотребление

> Наконец-**то** я дома.
>
> Наконец я дома.

I wonder how these two phrases differ in meaning? Adding the colloquial particle "то" to the end of an adverb seems to reinforce its meaning, but at the risk of coming across as somewhat childish and uneducated.

In German, for instance, the adverb "endlich" single-handedly carries the connotation of emotional relief (like, "Ah, FINALLY!") after a long-lasting wait is over.

Is the adverb "Наконец" alone not enough to impart a sense of relief to the sentence?

Comment: "Наконец-то" can be a standalone phrase. "Наконец" should be a part in a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that `наконец-то` is fit for simple sentences (not compound or complex) with just one predicate, where the fact of something having occurred **finally** is its only idea.

> Наконец-то я дома.(simple sentence) Теперь можно расслабиться.

`наконец` almost implies some continuation or expansion of the statement

> Наконец я дома и могу расслабиться. (two predicates)
>   Наконец я дома, и можно расслабиться. (compound sentence)

Comment: @Alone-zee hi, yeah, sure

Comment: @Alone-zee no problem, i wasn't aware they set a time limit for recording, alright, the comment is deleted

Answer (score 4):

The version *with* -**то** (close to '*at last*') typically relates to the current moment and also expresses the speaker's *personal* (or related to a fictional character's thoughts) satisfaction with some *long awaited* fact, with a bit of emotion.

> **Наконец-то** мне принесли заказанный диск!

The more common version (*without* -**то**, closer to '*finally*') is *less personal* and can describe a sequence of some events in the past (not only recent events), which had been *expected* but happened with some delay (or inevitably not as soon as desired).

> В 1830 году Наталья Гончарова согласилась, **наконец**, выйти замуж за
>   Пушкина.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is absolutely the same "at last", but as you mentioned (correctly ) the difference is emotional, since "-то", a particle gives an additional stress to the word it is used with.

> Наконец я дома. (I am home at last.) Наконец-то я дома.(And at last I am home).